# Java ObjectOutputStream and updating a file

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am having trouble figuring out one implementation problem, I have one class, it behaves like list but instead of holding a file in some collection it saves them on a disk.

The problem occurs when I want to add some element to my list. At the start of my file I have one int that tells me how many objects there are in my list, but I can't figure out elegant way to update this value. I have something like this:

```
   public boolean add(T element)
{
    try 
    {
        out.writeObject(element);
        out.flush();
        //and here we need to update the int in my file
    } catch (IOException e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return true;
}
```

I tried to use something like this:

```
ObjectOutputStream upd=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(data.getAbsolutePath(),true));
```

but as I observed it writes some data to the start of the file, some serialization header or sth, how can I update single entry in my file or how to change

```
ObjectOutputStream
```

"pointer" to write at the beginning of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Typically with stream based classes (especially higher order streams like OOS), you should rewrite the whole file, anytime you update it.

If you really INSIST on only updating part of a file, then you should think of the file as made up of N streams, where each 'stream' represents one object that you are writing. So i would use a RandomAccessFile for the base file, and then when i want to write an object i would wrap an ObjectOutputStream on top of a ByteArrayOutputStream, write your object into that, then take those bytes, and rewrite those bytes into the RandomAcessFile where you want.

This probably won't be particularly efficient, as you will write N OOS headers, and N class descriptions for the object you are writing.

Comment: I was thinking about rewriting the whole file only if I won't find any other solution, so there is no way to update first entry of my file?

Comment: Thanks for advices, for now I settled for one file - one entry, I will see if it will work out, if not I will change my implementation to one file and rewriting.

Comment: To rewrite the whole file, would that essentially mean just deserializing all its data into an ArrayList, performing the modifications you want on such data, deleting the file, and then writing the contents of the ArrayList to a newly-created file of the old file's name?